# SQLConnection not fully becoming a new connection using new ConsoleApp

Tags: c#, foreach, console-application

This one is tough to explain inside the title.  What I have going on is a foreach loop that sets a new connection string for each target server and database.  However, when the foreach loop comes around, it sets the string as intended however, the SqlConnection remains looking at the the first string.

Below is what I'm using to call the connection:

```
 foreach (string DatabaseConfig in DataHoldingClass.Server_Database_Config)
            {
                string[] splitConfig = DatabaseConfig.Split('|');

                //set sql connection config
                DataHoldingClass.Database = splitConfig[0];
                DataHoldingClass.SQLSERVER = splitConfig[1];

                //open specific config


                SQLProcessorClass.SQLMASTERCONNECTION =  SQLProcessorClass.OpenSQLConnection();

                //do some work here
                SQLProcessorClass.SQLMASTERCONNECTION.Dispose();
}
```

Below is what i'm using to set the connection:

```
public static string masterConString = "server="+DataHoldingClass.SQLSERVER+";database ="+DataHoldingClass.Database+";Trusted_Connection=Yes;persist security info=False;connection timeout=500";

    public static SqlConnection SQLMASTERCONNECTION { get; set; }

    public static SqlConnection OpenSQLConnection()
    {
        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(masterConString);
        sqlCon.Open();
        return sqlCon;
    }
```

And below is DataHoldingClass

```
  public static string Database { get; set; }
    public static string SQLSERVER { get; set; }
```

so for example my string DatabaseConfig = "Database1|Server1" and the next loop in the DataHoldClass.Server_Database_Config is "Database2|Server2", when the loop happens the second time around it continues using "Database1|Server1" even though it's on the second string of the loop.

Any ideas?

Oh, I'm not actually calling the `Database` function even though stackoverflow is highlight that in blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted does not call a getter to change the static string `masterConString`, so will use the one created the first time you create a `SQLProcessorClass` object and remain set to that.

You could simplify to:

```
foreach (string DatabaseConfig in DataHoldingClass.Server_Database_Config) 
{ 
    string[] splitConfig = DatabaseConfig.Split('|');
    string connectionString = "server=" + splitConfig[1] + ";database =" + splitConfig[0] +
               ";Trusted_Connection=Yes;persist security info=False;connection timeout=500";

    using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        cnn.Open();

        // do work....

    }
}
```

Perhaps add try/catch and some checking such as `splitConfig.Length  >= 2`

Comment: yeah , unfortunately that SQL Class that has the connection would require a major change to a lot of code.  I need to keep it there, what is an easy what to set it in the code i have up top.

Comment: if you want to keep over complicated code (and if it wasn't, then this error probably would not have occurred) that's your choice. Creating a wrapper around connections, and making code that didn't create the connection responsible for closing it can lead to problems. I like to keep things simple. Also, you don't need to change alot of code if all you want to do is simplify the code you posted; just use something similiar to what I posted.

Answer (score 0):

The static string initialized outside of the loop is your problem.

Use local scope, perhaps something more like this.

```
string connectionStringTemplate = "server={0};database={1};Trusted_Connection=Yes;persist security info=False;connection timeout=500";
foreach (string DatabaseConfig in DataHoldingClass.Server_Database_Config) {
  // is this string parsing really necessary - why not separate variables?
  string[] splitConfig = DatabaseConfig.Split('|'); 
  // 0=database and 1=server, apparently from above
  string connectionString = String.Format(connectionStringTemplate, splitConfig[1], splitConfig[0]); 
  using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    //do some work here
  }
}
```

Also, the whole purpose of this console app might be avoidable.  Check out `sp_msforeachdb` for a c#-less solution provided you're on a single server.  RedGate tools can be used to execute across multiple.